# InstallShield Error 7132 -- An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support file .. Setup.inx

Tags: installshield

Nearing completion, InstallShield 2010 running under Vista is failing with the following message:

ISDEV : error -7132: An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support file
..\Release..\Setup.inx

where Release is the directory from which InstallShield was launched.  This error is fatal.
The InstallShield build aborts, and no installer is created.

Insofar as watching Windows Explorer would reveal, I see no evidence of the Setup.inx
file being created.  I suspected some kind of Windows file protection problem, but 
peculiarly, the larger tree in which this problem occurs has uniform protections, and I 
can make other installers within other parts of the tree without any difficulty.  The
other installers have been created with more or less the same methodology and deal with
similar directory configurations.

I would appreciate any thoughts on what might be the nature of this problem, both in
general and with regard to any specific theories.  I've read elsewhere that error 7132
captures a sort of grab bag of possible errors.

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

There can be following 2 reasons

1. If either *.rul file in script folder is empty or missing.
2. Install shield generate many run time files and we sometimes check them into source control/TFS, thus making them read only. Make sure that all files in script folder, except *.rul are deleted or made writable.

Comment: For me the `.rul` file was missing. Simply downloading the file from TFS solved my error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of known causes for this error:

- An Unsupported Language Has Been Included
- Syntax Error in the Installscript Code
- Hebrew or Arabic Languages Have Been Included in a InstallShield 2009
  Project that Uses InstallScript Custom Actions Build a Patch with
- InstallShield 12 for an Installscript MSI Project    or a Basic MSI
  Project

Details see http://support.installshield.com/kb/view.asp?articleid=Q200303

Answer (score 1):

One more reason can be there for the 
ISDEV : error -7132: An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support file ..\Release..\Setup.inx. 
If you mistakenly deleted the 'Script Files' folder or contents inside it, The same error will occur.

Workaroud: Create a new script in 'Behaviour and Logic -> InstallScript', this will create a script for you in 'Script Files' folder and work smoothly.

Please consider the Kevin Wan's answer for other issues.